# Accessing URL/URI information in Rails in the environments file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I would like to access the ActionController::Request from within the environments/development.rb file so that I can set a global variable there depending on the domain name. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931999/accessing-url-uri-information-in-rails-in-the-environments-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing URL/URI information in Rails in the environments file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931999/accessing-url-uri-information-in-rails-in-the-environments-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the environment files are loaded before any requests are made, so `ActionController::Request` doesn't exist at that time. What do you need to set and why (there may be other solutions to this)?